# Images uploaded from Macbook Pro Retina are huge?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there anyway to tweak the sizing of double pixel images uploaded from Macbook Pro Retina's to avoid them looking huge?

For example, the image from [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/20809/594) is double size

[image]

Comment: Retina is a high resolution device-- normal devices will use the name number of pixels, but it'll take twice the size on the screen because of the reduced pixel density. It would look normal-sized on other retina displays.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the user to just edit the files before uploading; the user could lower the resolution or shrink the entire image.

Comment: That's partially unfair-- the user might not realize that they're subjecting normal sub-1300$ pc users to large images. I would say that SE should have a feature to normalize images based on the image's DPI (does it have a DPI flag?)